# Is there a way to make WatiN click a link before the page finishes loading

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, watin

We're using WatiN for testing our UI, but one page (which is unfortunately not under our teams control) takes forever to finish loading.  Is there a way to get WatiN to click a link on the page before the page finishes rendering completely?

Comment: The time Watin waits is controlled by the WaitForLoadTimeout property. Here's a blog post which talks a little bit about it: <a href="http://blog.agilejedi.com/2008/08/watin-installed.html">http://blog.agilejedi.com/2008/08/watin-installed.html</a>

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that WatiN isn't waiting long enough, it's that it waits until the page loads before it does anything. We found the solution, load the page with `ClickNoWait()` Then look for the link on the page as normal, but call `WaitUntilExists()` on the link before calling `Click()`. This way WatiN will click the link as soon as it is loaded, not wait until the whole page is loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the code we found to work:

```
IE browser = new IE(....);
browser.Button("SlowPageLoadingButton").ClickNoWait();
Link continueLink = browser.Link(Find.ByText("linktext"));
continueLink.WaitUntilExists();
continueLink.Click();
```

Comment: +1 for answering yourself to your question ;) And good answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leave out the call to WaitUntilExists() since WatiN does this internally when you call a method or property on an element (like the link.Click() in you rexample).

HTH,
Jeroen van Menen
Lead dev WatiN

Comment: But I'm not calling click, I'm calling ClickNoWait()  doesn't that mean that it won't wait unless I call WaitUntilExists()?